# Stop button from refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a jQuery button from refreshing the page without any luck.

The code snippet I am using is:

```
jQuery( "<button>" )
  .text( "Show help" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    tooltips.tooltip( "open" );
  })
  .insertAfter( "#myForm" );
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `jQuery("<button>")`? Use `$` instead of `jQuery` and `<button>` isn't gonna work; try `$("button")`

Comment: Add return false after tooltips.tooltip("open"); statement. This will stop propagating the click action

Comment: If you don't add type="button" it'll default to submit type, hence the refresh

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `jQuery( "<button>" )` to `jQuery( "button" )`.

The reason for this is jQuery needs to be passed something that [looks like a CSS selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/) (although as a sidenote jQuery uses Sizzle and has its [own special selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), but any CSS selector will also work in jQuery).

Using `jQuery('button')` will return a jQuery-wrapped array of all `<button>` elements on the page. You can then use this list to add things like click listeners with `.click()`, for example.

You should know that `jQuery('<button>')` is valid, though. But, it is used for another purpose. It returns a new `<button>` element that you can modify with JS and then insert into the DOM with a function like `appendChild()`. It does something like this:

```
function makebutton() {
    return document.createElement('button');
}
```

Comment: You are correct. However, you could make this answer more helpful by explaining why the first line is incorrect but the second works.

Comment: Thanks PhpMyCoder for your advise. :)